# How can I  refresh a combobox after modifying its ItemsSource ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, observablecollection

The problems is simple: when `ItemsSource` is updated Combobox doesn't "refresh" e.g. new items don't appear to be added to the list of items in the combobox.

I've tried the solution from aceepted answer to this question: [WPF - Auto refresh combobox content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371857/wpf-auto-refresh-combobox-content) with no luck.

here's my code,
XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="LeadTypeComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding LeadTypeCollection}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<XmlNode> LeadTypeCollection { get; set; }
```

the way I update this collection is in the separate method, which loads data from updated XML file: `this.LeadTypeCollection  = GetLeadTypesDataSource();`

I've also tried using `Add` for testing purposes:

```
this.LeadTypeCollection = GetLeadTypesDataSource();
ItemToAdd = LeadTypeCollection[LeadTypeCollection.Count - 1];
this.LeadTypeCollection.Add(ItemToAdd);
```

the code updating collection definitely kicks off, I can see new items in this collection when debugging, but I don't see them in the combobox.

Doing this in the xaml code-behind works: `LeadTypeComboBox.ItemsSource = MyViewModel.GetLeadTypesDataSource();` but I'd like to achieve this with MVVM, i.e. the code must be in ViewModel which isn't aware of LeadTypeComboBox control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I have seen this before and the solution was to update the collection property to raise the change.

i.e.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<XmlNode> leadTypeCollection;

    public string LeadTypeCollection
    { 
        get { return leadTypeCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (value != leadTypeCollection)
            {
                leadTypeCollection = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LeadTypeCollection");
            }
        }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        leadTypeCollection = new ObservableCollection<XmlNode>();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChanged.Raise(this, info);
    }
}
```

I have an extension method for raising the property (as found elsewhere on stackoverflow):

```
public static void Raise(this PropertyChangedEventHandler handler, object sender, string propertyName)
{
    if (null != handler)
    {
        handler(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, ok, ViewModel should inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and your solution works with implemented `PropertyChangedEventHandler`

Comment: Yes that's right. I will tidy up the code a little though :-)

Comment: Shouldn't `LeadTypeCollection` be of type `ObservableCollection<XmlNode>` and not `string`?

Answer (score 10):

Firedragons answer would work, but i would prefer to initialize the LeadTypeCollection just once and use clear, add remove to update your collection.

```
var update = GetLeadTypesDataSource();     
this.LeadTypeCollection.Clear();

foreach(var item in update)
{
   this.LeadTypeCollection.Add(item);
}
```

your xaml binding should work if the datacontext is right

```
<ComboBox Name="LeadTypeComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding LeadTypeCollection}" />
```

Comment: That's the way I tend to do it too. The ObservableCollections built in property raising works well. The situation I showed is where you change the entire list which I guess doesn't raise a change

Comment: np your solution works well :) but i like my approach more. and as far as you work with ICollectionView for sorting and filtering - its easier to do it my way.

Answer (score 7):

A simple method is to change ItemsSource with empty list and then change it back to your updated source. A snippet from my project which is working:

```
        RulesTable.ItemsSource = Rules.rulesEmpty;
        RulesTable.ItemsSource = Rules.Get();
```