# How to link 2 comboboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes each with 2 methods for _Loaded and _Selection changed

i want to select a location in the first combobox and then the next combobox should list a bunch of dates for that specific location

Here is what i have so far:

```
    <ComboBox 
    x:Name="comboBoxLocation" 
    Text="Lokation"       
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,305,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"  
    Width="120" 
    Loaded="ComboBoxLocation_Loaded" 
    SelectionChanged="ComboBoxLocation_SelectionChanged"/>

    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxDate" 
    Text="Dato" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="195,305,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
    Loaded="ComboBoxDate_Loaded"  
    SelectionChanged="ComboBoxDate_SelectionChanged"/>
```

and

```
    private void ComboBoxLocation_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBoxLocation = sender as ComboBox;

        comboBoxDate.SelectedIndex = 0;
        comboBoxDate.ItemsSource = controller.GetBusTimes();

        //ComboBoxDate_Loaded(sender, e);
    }

    private void ComboBoxDate_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> dataDate = controller.GetBusTimes();

        var comboBoxDate = sender as ComboBox;

        comboBoxDate.ItemsSource = dataDate;
    }
```

This seems to be a lot more difficult than i expected... I am starting to think that i might have madesome fundamental mistake here...

I have been fiddling around with this... I can manage to show a list of locations in the first box and the relevant dates for that location the second box. But when i change the first location, the dates stay the same...

How would i go about this?

Comment: I would bind the selected item of the first combobox to a property in your viewmodel and in the setter I would change the collection (which should be observable) of items in another property, which is also bound in the GUI. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: *"have madesome fundamental mistake"* - you are using wpf like it's winforms, so you inherit all binding issues of latter. With the MVVM pattern use it's very easy to create master/details relationship of data. E.g. binding collection of items to one combobox `ItemsSource` (and displaying only location), which `SelectedItem` is bound to property in setter of which you update details (create another collection and rise notification) bound to second combobox `ItemsSource`.

Comment: And your mistake is actually trying to use `Loaded` event. It's rised only once. Rather re-set `comboBoxDate.ItemsSource` in the `comboBoxLocation_SelectionChanged`. I see you tried that (commented line), you may have to do it in 2 steps (setting it first to `null`).

Comment: I'm not sure he has heard or used MVVM. Maybe someone should introduce how MVVM makes it easy to accomplish what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have used this to link 2 comboboxes in my windows form application.

By default set both comboboxes selection to 0 //Combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

```
 private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var combobox1VALUE= combobox1.Text;
    }

private void combobox2_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //Select datasouece according to combobox 1 data selection(combobox1VALUE) 
            combobox2.Items.Clear();
          //add data to combobox2

        }
```

Comment: Did you understand the OP at all?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code.

1. It is not clear where & how controller.GetBusTimes() gets information about changed location?
   If somehow the above-mentioned function is in know of location change and is still not showing updated info in another combo box then
2. See also this answer on how to [refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914549/how-can-i-refresh-a-combobox-after-modifying-its-itemssource-observablecollecti) combo box display once ItemSource is changed

Answer (score 0):

Why not to bind separately Item source and selected item?

```
<Combobox ItemsSource="{Binding ItempsProperty}" SelectedItem="{Binding StrValueProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

And you could set one property in the setter of other